# En quoi la nouvelle orthographe française aura-t-elle un impact important sur les textes et la prononciation ? Sera-t-elle plus facile à apprendre ?

Tags: prononciation, orthographe

Apparemment, une nouvelle orthographe sera mise en place dès la prochaine rentrée scolaire, *([voir cet article](http://www.lesoir.be/1111851/article/actualite/france/2016-02-04/ognon-nenufar-weekend-france-va-appliquer-nouvelle-orthographe) et [ce site](http://www.orthographe-recommandee.info/))*

Elle consiste en bref à simplifier la ponctuation et les accents.

Est-ce que ceci pourrait simplifier la prononciation ou le contraire ?

Je prends ci-dessous l'exemple du mot *oignon*/*ognon* :

Orthographe actuelle :

> Il éplucha un oignon.

Nouvelle Orthographe :

> Il éplucha un ognon.

Après vérification ; la prononciation est la même, ce qui évite d'entendre le *i* de o*i*gnon.

Quels sont les buts recherchés par la nouvelle orthographe ?

Comment: C'est une question uniquement basé sur l'opinion personnelle. C'est difficile de répondre...

Comment: On parle d'appliquer la [réforme de 1990](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifications_orthographiques_du_fran%C3%A7ais_en_1990) ici.

Comment: Marrant, j'ai eu la discussion en famille sur ce mot précisément. Perso je vois ça comme un bénéfice pour l'apprenant. Toutes ces exceptions n'ayant aucune autre origine qu'un héritage étymologique, ne font que complexifier( ou enrichir, selon le point de vue) la langue. Je suis en tout cas content car à l'avenir je ne devrais sans doute pas expliquer à ma fille pourquoi "Oignon" et "Pognon" se prononcent à l'identique, contrairement à "Oignon" et "Moignon"...

Comment: Les règles existantes restent en vigueur, c'est une nouvelle d'orthographe dans les manuels scolaires. Les deux orthographes sont possibles désormais. La prononciation sera la même et l'écriture ressemblera d'avantage à la manière dont on le prononce. Quant à la facilité de l'apprendre... je n'en ai aucune idée. Je pense qu'il faut attendre les résultats officiels après que nos chères têtes blondes aient servi de cobaye.

Comment: Ma crainte est que la nouvelle orthographe devienne un marqueur social, séparant ceux qui ont les moyens éducatifs d'apprendre l'ancienne et la nouvelle de ceux n'apprenant que la nouvelle. J'espère que l'avenir me donnera tort.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- La nouvelle orthographe ne change rien à la prononciation,
- Elle élimine certains problèmes liés à l'évolution de la typographie depuis Gutenberg,
- De nombreuses incohérences sont ainsi éliminées,
- Elle ne touche pas l'étymologie.

De toutes façons :

- Elle fait couler beaucoup d'encre, et ramène les souvenirs des anciens  qui ont passé le *Certificat d'Études* avec la moyenne et plus en orthographe,
- Elle diminue le nombre d'exceptions orthographiques,
- Elle fera râler par principe une partie des français... qui s'en accommoderont plus vite qu'ils ne l'imaginent !

---

P.S. :

La réforme est subtile et résout bon nombre d'anomalies qui étaient un héritage du temps où les imprimeurs utilisaient les *[casses](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casse_%28typographie%29)*  et où certaines graphies résultaient d'influences régionales.

Pour une fois, elle a été réalisée en pleine concertation et non imposée par un ordre politique.

Elle ne touche pas à l’étymologie et les mots gardent toute leur profondeur sémantique.

Comment: Même si j'aime l'ancienne orthographe, certains changements sont utiles (la nouvelle écriture des nombres évite les incompréhension, surtout en ordinal). La soudure toutefois me laisse perplexe, mais il n'y aura au moins plus de doute sur les accord. Peut-être sur la prononciation. Doit-on écrire « grandmère » et « grandchose » désormais ?

Comment: @Chop -- On est passé de grand'mère à grand-mère(s) ou mère(s)-grand des fables... *grand* ne s'accordant pas, on pourrait supprimer le `-` ; j'ai décidé de ne plus m’agiter les neurones, en cas de doute, je consulte mon dico ! Et puis si mon correcteur orthographique mélange un peu l'ancienne et la nouvelle, tous mes lecteurs n'ont pas la sévérité tatillonne des instituteurs de mon enfance :)... et parfois, il m'arrive de laisser passer des erreurs plus graves, malgré les relectures !

Comment: J'utilisais donc déjà la nouvelle orthographe pour ce mot. Je me doutais que mon français était un mélange d'orthographes pré- et post-1990 (je choisis ce qui m'intéresse en fonction de ce qui me semble avoir du sens, préférant de temps à autre la nouvelle graphie mais généralement l'ancienne pour conserver les traces historiques que sont les circonflexes).

Comment: @Chop -- Ah! "Le chapeau de la *c**i**me* est tombé dans l'*ab**î**me*"... souvenirs d'encre violette, raclée au fond de l'encrier par la plume sergent major !

Answer (score 1):

Il est vrai que l'orthographe d'aujourd'hui n'est pas facile à apprendre.
Pourtant elle est la marque de notre civilisation qui a pioché dans le grec et le latin pour s'exprimer. Mais, si on prend la peine de décomposer les mots en racine, préfixe et suffixe, pour peu que l'on se souvienne de quelques bribes de latin et de grec, on arrive non seulement à comprendre les mots nouveaux (pour ne pas dire les néologismes, *néo* comme « nouveau » et *logisme* de « langue ») mais aussi à les orthographier !