# Phrase interrogative avec inversion verbe et sujet

Tags: grammaire, interrogative, inversion

J'ai cette phrase avec deux pronoms :

> Les deux fauteuils, est-ce je **vous** **les** laisse au rez-de-chaussée ?

Avec l'inversion du verbe et du sujet, ça devient :

> Les deux fauteuils, **vous** **les** laisse-je au rez-de-chaussée ?

Est-ce correct ?

Answer (score 4):

À la première phrase, il ne manque qu’un petit mot :

> Les deux fauteuils, est-ce ***que*** je vous les laisse au rez-de-chaussée ?

Quant à la seconde, elle est correcte à un accent près :

> Les deux fauteuils, vous les laissé-je au rez-de-chaussée ? <sub>ancienne orthographe</sub>
>   Les deux fauteuils, vous les laissè-je au rez-de-chaussée ? <sub>nouvelle orthographe</sub>

Quelque notes concernant cette forme, cependant :

- Le *É* que l’on ajoute en inversion interrogative à la première personne à l’indicatif présent des verbes où cette conjugaison se termine par un E caduc se prononce *È*, ce qui justifia [le changement orthographique](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/frtraitunionquestion.php) proposé par la réforme de 1990. L’ancienne orthographe demeure valide jusqu’à nouvel ordre, et les deux graphies sont donc acceptables<sup>1</sup>.
- Cette forme d’inversion à la première personne n’est guère courante à l’oral, qui passera souvent au pronom *on*, qui est par sa nature imprécis, mais que l’on peut habituellement préciser à la lumière des circonstances :

  > Les deux fauteuils, vous les laisse-t-on au rez-de-chaussée ?

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Ce qui ne veut pas dire que les gens en général n’ont pas leur opinion propre quant au système à privilégier... Voir à ce sujet certaines questions sur ce site, pour lesquelles les réponses et commentaires laissent voir une certaine dissension :</sub>

- <sub>[En quoi la nouvelle orthographe française aura-t-elle un impact important sur les textes et la prononciation ? Sera-t-elle plus facile à apprendre ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/17668/13100)</sub>
- <sub>[Doit-on écrire « sûrement » ou « surement » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/7228/13100)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

> Les deux fauteuils, vous les laissé-je au rez-de-chaussée ?

C'est la phrase correcte. Concernant l'autre phrase, vous avez oublié le *que*.

> Les deux fauteuils, est-ce que je vous les laisse au rez-de-chaussée ?

Je ne suis pas un locuteur natif mais je pense que, pour des raisons phonétiques, l'inversion de je au présent de l'indicatif, par exemple dans *parlé-je, laissé-je, aimé-je, prends-je,* etc. est plutôt rare.

On préfère la construction *est-ce que* à l'oral comme à l'écrit. Par ailleurs, à l'oral, on peut aussi employer la structure affirmative avec une intonation montante.

Cependant, *ai-je, dis-je, fais-je, suis-je, vais-je, vois-je* sont encore en usage (du moins, ma grammaire indique cela). De plus, *puis-je* est toujours utilisé au lieu de *peux-je*.

Cf. ma question ici :

[Simple inversion with je](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30207/simple-inversion-with-je)

Comment: Un bel ajout sur ma réponse de présenter les verbes pour lesquels l'inversion est plus courante à la première personne. +1